# Is this the correct function for table creation in database in php?

Tags: php

Initialising variables

```
<? php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pword = '';
$dbname = 'mydb';
$tablename = 'userdata';
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pword);
```

Is this the correct code of the table creation function?(
Assuming we have connected to the Database)

```
 function createtable($tablename) {

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pword); 
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
        $tablename(uid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      firstname char(60),
      lastname char(60),
      username varchar(60),
      password varchar(60),
      gender enum('male','female') NOT NULL,
      course set('PHP','HTML','CSS','Javascript'),
      comments longtext,
      PRIMARY KEY(uid)
      )";
 if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
 echo "Table created.";
}
else 
{
echo "Error in creating table.";
}       
}
```

?>

Comment: Maybe better for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: no,and why you need a function to create same table on each call

Comment: @FerozAkbar coz if it not exists

Comment: I want to create the same table just once,but using my own function

Comment: I want to create the same table just once,but using my own function,so I will have to check if the table already exists or not.If it already exists then it should throw an error else it should create the table for the first time run of this code

Comment: we can not tell you if a function is correct or not for XYZ. correctness implies a definition what correct is, including the test on how to test for correctness. This information is not part of your question. Additionally, Stackoverflow is for generic, concrete programming questions, not for personal tutoring requests. Please restrain from posting those (many of your question are of that kind). This is not how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about personal tutoring and code-review.

Answer (score 2):

Little change. Just suggestion to pass `$con` & `$tablename` parameters to `createtable()` and finally call the `createtable()` function.

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pword = '';
$dbname = 'mydb';
$tablename = 'userdata';
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pword, $dbname);
function createtable($con, $tablename) {
//mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pword);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
  $tablename(uid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  firstname char(60),
  lastname char(60),
  username varchar(60),
  password varchar(60),
  gender enum('male','female') NOT NULL,
  course set('PHP','HTML','CSS','Javascript'),
  comments longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY(uid)
  )";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($result){echo "Table created.";}
else{echo mysqli_error($con);}
}
createtable($con, $tablename);
```